# Rollup in SQL is not giving desired output when we use CASE in select Statement

Tags: sql-server

I am using the below query. But when I try to do ROLLUP the column with CASE statement does not show the total in the result for that column. Can anyone help on this? I am trying my hands on.

I am out of options and topics available on net is not helpful. So, the query produces the total for all the columns but not for the column with the CASE statement. I have just provided a rough work not the actual query.

```
select   
A,
sum(B),
sum(C),
sum(D),
case when sum(D) = 0  then 0
        else (sum(B)-Sum(C))/Sum(D) as E
from table
group by A with ROLLUP
```

I am using CASE just because the column D sometimes has 0 as a value and that cannot be used to divide. Any help is appreciated. So the column with CASE is not getting rolled up. Please help. I am stuck on this.

Comment: It should be GROUP BY ROLLUP (A) (if you're using MS SQL server as you've tagged in your question). Try to see what happens without the ROLLUP. Could you please post the result set in such a case?

Comment: Using ROLLUP before or after doesn't make a difference.
    E
    0.20 
    0.20
    0.28 
    0.29 
    0.28 
    0.11 
    0.30 
    0.37 
    0.23 
    0.39 
    0.00 
    0.00 
    0.20 
So the last value should be a total rather then a value from the column. I am sorry I am not able to show you result as in column format.

Comment: Sample data and expected output would really help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if you have used end while using case statement, looks like end is missing? From my understanding you would like to add the total generated from the case statement as well. Since E is not a preexisting column, you may need to use sub query to get you expected output.

```
Create sample Data: 

Select '2019-01-16' as A, 100 as B,         10 as C , 0 as  D 
into #temp union all 
select '2019-01-16' as A, 200 as B,         20 as C , 0 as  D union all 
select '2019-01-17' as A, 300 as B,         30 as C , 10 as D  union all 
select '2019-01-17' as A, 300 as B,         40 as C , 20 as D  union all 
select '2019-01-28' as A, 300 as B,         50 as C , 0 as  D union all 
select '2019-01-28' as A, 400 as B,         60 as C , 50 as D 


select A, 
sum(B) B ,
sum(C) C ,
sum(D) D ,
sum(E) E   from (
select   
A,
sum(B) B ,
sum(C) C ,
sum(D) D ,
case when sum(D) = 0  then 0
else (sum(B)-Sum(C))/Sum(D) end   as E
from #temp
group by A ) tst
group by  A  with ROLLUP`
```

Output: 
`A            B  C   D   E
2019-01-16  300 30  0   0
2019-01-17  600 70  30  17
2019-01-28  700 110 50  11
NULL       1600 210 80  28`

Comment: It worked. Thanks for your time and effort. I was not able to provide actual data due to restrictions. Sorry for that. You are a Gem. :-)